# How to show javascript files in the "JavaScript Resources" on Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, resources

I'm trying to add my jsx files (javascript-ish files for [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/)) to the Eclipse's (Neon 4.6) "JavaScript Resources" resources folder, but with no luck. I want to accomplish the same behaviour as the "Java Resources" folder and/or a linked folder, just like the custom "React Resources" in the following image:

[image: proof].

**NOTE:** "React Resources" is linked to "Portal/src/main/react".